# Not able to clone existing or new git repository using SSH

Tags: git, ssh, ssh-keys

I have setup few bare repositories on my **Windows SBS 2011 server**. This server is locally connected to my Windows machine. I am trying to clone the repository using **SSH**. I am getting following error when cloning existing or new repositories:

[image]

I tried following approaches without any success:

1. Disable firewall and anti-virus on the local server
2. Checked Inbound outbound rules for port 22
3. I tried multiple git clients such as **GitGui** and **GitEye**

I have following questions:

1. The issue is also happening with my **previously working repositories**. What can cause such problem?
2. Is there a problem with the SSH connection between the local server and client machine?

I would appreciate any suggestions and thoughts on this topic.

**EDIT:**

I tried connecting to the local server from terminal using following command:

```
ssh admin@192.168.1.106
```

Output:

```
Connection closed by 192.168.1.106 port 22
```

Comment: Try connecting to the server with a plain ssh client, using the same username and password or key. Then [edit] your question to show exactly what you did and what happened.

Comment: Please refer to the edit section.